# specifying file descriptor number?

Tags: c, linux, bash, unix, file-descriptor

My understanding was that one could not control the file descriptor (integer) assigned by the OS when opening a new file using open().  How then is it possible in a bash shell to assign a specific file descriptor using a command like

```
exec 5>&1
```

(I suppose I could find out by reading the bash sources...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you are right that sometimes file descriptors may already be in use. I got this from http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html#FTN.AEN17716

"Using file descriptor 5 might cause problems. When Bash creates a child process, as with exec, the child inherits fd 5 (see Chet Ramey's archived e-mail, [SUBJECT: RE: File descriptor 5 is held open](http://groups.google.com/group/gnu.bash.bug/browse_thread/thread/13955daafded3b5c/18c17050087f9f37)). Best leave this particular fd alone."

The solutiont to this is specified in section 3.6 paragraph 2 of the bash manual.

> *Each redirection that may be preceded by a file descriptor number may instead be
>   preceded by a word of the form `{varname}`. In this case, for each redirection operator
>   except >&- and <&-, the shell will allocate a file descriptor greater than 10 and assign it to {varname}. If >&- or <&- is preceded by {varname}, the value of varname defines the file descriptor to close.*

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

exec {NEW_STDOUT}>&1
echo "Hello" >&$NEW_STDOUT
exec {NEW_STDOUT}>&-
```

Answer (score 3):

See the [dup2](http://www.manpagez.com/man/2/dup2/) Unix system call.

Comment: This explains how I can dup 2 to 5, but how do I know that 5 is available? What if it is already in use?

Comment: http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html
`If fildes2 is already a valid open file descriptor, it shall be closed first, unless fildes is equal to fildes2 in which case dup2() shall return fildes2 without closing it.`

Answer (score 1):

Also, file descriptors are assigned sequentially, so if you know 0, 1, 2, ..., n are already opened and none of them have been closed, the next will be n+1.

Comment: Fine, but how can bash be certain that 5 is not already opened? (And what does exec do if it is?)

Comment: Bash probably uses `dup2`. And it's careful not to have random file descriptors open when it forks a child process to run a command.

Comment: @c-urchin: if you haven't opened 5, it is unlikely that it will be in use.